# I'm new to kotlin, can any one help how to println(originalList[i]) out side the function

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val originalList = arrayOf("sathish", "ramesh", "kumar", "rajesh", "ram", "kom")

    for (i in 1..1)
    {
       var t: Int = ((Math.random() * originalList.count()).toInt())
       println("Num $i : " +t)
    }

}
println(originalList[i])
```

Comment: Please add some context to question. Also look at how you should post code in community. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

s-k, you have any mistakes here:

for (i in 1..1) ****(only 1 until 1 its give 1 time)

println(originalList[i]) ****(its is out of for statment {})

one ajustment suggest is :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{

    val originalList = arrayOf("sathish", "ramesh", "kumar", "rajesh", "ram", "kom")


    for (i in 0..(originalList.size - 1)) {

       var t: Int = ((Math.random() * originalList.count()).toInt())

       println("Num $i : $t -> ${originalList[i]}")

     }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I need only one output at a time. But I need it printed outside the function, something like an output of the function that I can reuse in a different function.